# FTP Reverse Proxy for Blue-Green Deployment

Tags: networking, proxy, ftp, reverse-proxy

My company wants to implement [Blue-Green Deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html). This is how it's supposed to work: we have a stage server and a production server. Both servers serve different versions of our website and also allow clients to upload files over ftp.

I created a linux instance with nginx and set it up to proxy http traffic to one of those two servers. Also there is a bash script for switching ip-address of the server nginx sends traffic to.

Now I need to do the same for ftp: clients connect to linux server, it forward/proxies traffic to another server.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using the [`mod_proxy`](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy) module for ProFTPD; it can handle proxying (forward *and* reverse) of FTP/FTPS connections.

*Full disclaimer: I'm the author of `mod_proxy` and ProFTPD.*